# Someone is trying to delete the Memorable Titles thread

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

There is currently a vote to delete this very old thread.  I am writing to register my *strong* protest against this and bring it to the attention of other users here on meta.

[Most memorable titles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles)

Comment: There are currently 4 votes to reopen, one more is needed.

Comment: Voted to reopen. It is true that it is a list question, but I find it quite interesting.

Answer (score 12):

If there's one vote to delete, you shouldn't worry about it too much; it takes [10 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/295232) to delete a question which such a high score. Delete votes never expire, but the chances that it will accumulate so many votes are low.

I'd say that the question is rightfully closed (it's a textbook [list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/295232)); similar old questions around the network have got a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/295232), though that would prevent voting and editing.

Comment: I agree with the question remaining closed, but (even aside from my highly-upvoted answer) I think it should not be deleted.

Comment: The question has been reopened. Doesn’t this clear extant delete votes?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek no, but nobody (aside from moderators) can cast delete votes now.

Comment: I see. Thank you.